# Jquery Fatnav - active state doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a Jquery plugin called fatNav. 
https://github.com/Glitchbone/jquery-fatNav

Everything works just fine but I cant get my active state to work. The only way this works is if it is inline like so

```
<li><a href="index.php" style="color:#F00">Home</a></li>
```

but I would like to make it work in the style.css (external stylesheet)

The active and hover states are not in the jquery plugin's stylesheet.

I got hover to work like so

```
.fat-nav li a:hover {color: #F0F0F0}
```

but active doesn't work.

```
.fat-nav li a:active {color: #f00}
```

I'm using this in conjunction with Bootstrap but its the last line of my style.css so I don't think anything else should matter. I even used !important but even that doesn't work.

Can someone please be kind and help!

Answer (score 0):

Try add a class like

```
<li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li>
```

`.fat-nav li a.active {color: #f00}`